# How to append data to a line of a CSV file and move it using Python?

Tags: python, csv, file

I need to be able to add extra items to a pre-existing line of a CSV file dictated by a search algorithm based on a user input (the code for the search is already in place) and move the line now containing the added items into a different CSV file while erasing it from the old file

Code for the search:

```
found = False
while found == False:
  reg = input("\nEnter the registration number of the car sold\n")
  with open("Cars.csv") as sale:
    file = csv.reader(sale)
    for i in file:
      if i[2] == reg:
        found = True 
  if found != True:
    print("\nRegistration not found, please try again\n")
sale.close()
```

Code that writes to Cars.CSV:

```
if Choice1==1 and role==1:#buy a car
  confirm="n"
  while confirm!="y":
    fileopen = open("Cars.csv","a", newline="")
    file = csv.writer(fileopen)
    buyer=input("\nWhat is your name?\n")
    brand=input("\nWhat brand made the car?\n")
    colour=input("\nWhat colour is the car?\n")
    reg=input("\nWhat is the car's registration number?\n")
    broughtfor=input("\nHow much did the car cost?\n")
    date=input("\nWhat date was the car brought on?\n")
    data=[brand,colour,reg,broughtfor,date,buyer]
    #data inputed and compiled into a list
    confirm=input("Are you sure this information is correct\ny/n\n")#confirmation prompt
    if confirm=="y":
      file.writerow(data)#writing to file if confirmed
    if confirm != "y":
      Choice2=int(input("\nWould you like to:\n 1) Re-enter the information\n 2) Exit to the menue\n")) #allows reentry of data or a return to the menue
      if Choice2==2:
        confirm="y" #cancels the input
  fileopen.close()
  print("Thank you\n")
```

Code asking for the inputs that need to be added:

```
name=input("\nPlease enter your name\n")
price=int(input("\nHow much did this car sell for?\n"))
date=input("\nWhat date was the car sold?\n")
data=[price, date, name]
```

[an image of the table of test data I was given, the middle 3 columns are those that need to be added to the the rest and the last 2 are computed when needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHOns.jpg)

a line reads Brand:BMW, Colour:Silver, Reg:ABC123, Buy price:20000, Buy date:10 4 23, buyer:Adam, Sale Price:30000, Sale date:20 4 23, Seller:Daisy, Buyer com £:200, Seller com £:300

I am yet to test any code as I don't have any ideas of how to approach this problem

Comment: You can't delete or insert bytes from/into the middle of a file. You have to rewrite it (at least from the point of change to the end).

Comment: Show a sample of the Cars.csv file in order to clarify what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can remove an entry from the original file. Your description of what needs to go into some other file is confusing.

```
import csv

# open the file. note that we use 'r+' mode because we may rewrite it
with open(file='Cars.csv', mode='r+', newline='') as csvdata:
    # make an in-memory list of the csv data
    data = list(csv.reader(csvdata))
    reg = input('Enter registration number: ')
    # search the list
    for i, row in enumerate(data[1:], 1):
        # try to match the registration number
        if row[2] == reg:
            # remove entry from list
            data.pop(i)
            # go to BOF
            csvdata.seek(0)
            # rewrite the rows
            csv.writer(csvdata).writerows(data)
            # don't forget to truncate
            csvdata.truncate()
            break
    else:
        print('Not found')
```